# Is it possible to retrieve an IDL using getAccountInfo() without brute forcing anchor decode() on the accounts

Tags: anchor, anchor-program-idl, idl

Is there a pattern in which account the IDL is stored in?

Answer (score 3):

If there's an IDL published on-chain you can use `fetchIdl`

For example:

```
const IDL = await anchor.Program.fetchIdl(new PublicKey("...program ID here..."), provider);
```

Comment: Is it possible to get different versions of the IDL?